# Javascript call value from other input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="first value" />
    <input type="text" id="field2" onkeyup="showRSS(this.value, this.alt)" value="" alt="test">
</form>
```

Within the `showRSS()` onkeyup function I need to call the value from the first input field (`id="field1"`). How can I do that?

Comment: u need to use javascript for that separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use its ID with `document.getElementById()`:

So if you want to pass it as the third argument to `showRSS()`:

```
    <input type="text" id="field2" onkeyup="showRSS(this.value, this.alt, document.getElementById('field1').value)" value="" alt="test">
```

Or if you want to get it from within `showRss()`:

```
function showRSS( ... )
{
    var field1 = document.getElementById('field1').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of specific text boxes you can just iterate them in the function and grab the value of those you want based on their name. First, add a name to the second textbox as well then have such code:

```
function showRSS() {
    var oForm = document.forms[0]; //assuming only one form
    var desiredInputNames = { "field1": "", "field2": "" }; //names of elements to read
    for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
        var element = oForm.elements[i];
        if (desiredInputNames[element.name]) {
            var value = element.value;
            //handle the current value
        }
    }
}
```

(Using associative array rather than plain array for better searching)

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to do that...

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="first value" />
    <input type="text" id="field2" onkeyup="showRSS(this.value, this.alt, this.parentNode.getElementsByName('field1')[0].value)" value="" alt="test">
</form>
```

if you use `field1` as `name` outside the `form` tag, it won't create any problem...